# What is the bonus received for filling up a hotel floor?

Tags: tiny-tower-vegas

How many coins are received as a bonus for filling up a hotel room in Tiny Tower Vegas, and does it depend on the floor number or the upgrade level of the hotel room or both?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The bonus is dependent on the level of the hotel room and independent of floor number. The bonus scales to the 2nd power of upgrade level as follows:

```
b = 26.25*l^2 - 0.1*l + 1.75
```

Where b = bonus in coins, and l = upgrade level.

Level - Bonus
1 - 28
2 - 105
3 - 239
4 - 423
5 - 656
6 - 945
7 - 1287
8 - 1680
9 - 2126
10 - 2625

[image: Graph showing bonus received in coins vs upgrade level of hotel room.]

Comment: Can it go higher then 10?

Comment: @Mathias711, no, because you can only upgrade floors up to the 10th level.